# How do I access a script component added to a gameobject from an assembly in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

In my Unity project, I'm creating a game object and then adding a script to it at run time. The script (called Part in this case) is being added from an assembly. which ends up looking like this in the inspector: 
[image]
Which is not quite the appearance I'm used to seeing on a script component in the inspector. (notice the Unity logo icon.) The script does function as expected though so that part works. The PROBLEM is that when I attempt to access the Part script component on this GameObject from a different script, using the following code:

```
GameObject newPart = Instantiate(ContentManager.LoadPart(part), loc, Quaternion.Euler(rot)) as GameObject;
newPart.GetComponent<Part>().Load(N["Parts"][i]);
```

I receive the error shown in the screenshot indicating that "Part" is null.

My second concern is that using this method (adding scripts from assemblies) will prevent me from making a GetComponent call for a base class type and have it successfully access any scripts that inherit from the base class type requested.

So How do I access a script component added at runtime from an assembly? and can it work with inheritance as well?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "from an assembly?" because i dont think you mean you are actually trying to access it with assembly..

Comment: Recommend attaching a debugger to check which specific reference is null. I can imagine circumstances where `newPart` could be null, for example.

Comment: Actually @Andrew The script in question has been compiled with the mono compiler into a .dll file (assembly) and then loaded via System.Reflection so it can be added at run-time to the GameObject without the application knowing the code even existed. (I'm implementing a modding system for my game.)

Answer (score 0):

If your adding your script during runtime, then it must be done *after* instantiation, as before you instantiate the gameobject, it doesnt exist in the game hierarchy.

```
GameObject newPart = Instantiate(ContentManager.LoadPart(part), loc, Quaternion.Euler(rot)) as GameObject;

newPart.AddComponent<Part>();

newPart.GetComponent<Part>().Load(N["Parts"][i]);
```